# How can I return a value of the latest document version from an array of versions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Example from Excel]

I have an array of document versions that are automatically extracted from metadata. I need create a formula that would automatically return the value of the latest version. The versions are often positioned randomly, so I can't just return the value from right-hand-side column. The challenge is that all document revisions contain a letter. P for preliminary and C for Construction.

My concept of the formula is that it should look for "C" in the array and return the cell that contains "C" along with the largest number. In case "C" is absent, the formula should then look for "P" and return the cell that contains "P" along with the largest number. Finally, if both "C" and "P" are missing from the array, the the formula should return "N/A".

I appreciate this is a very specialized formula, but I have seen some amazing advice on these forums, so I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With data in **B1** through **F1**, in **A1** enter the array formula:

```
="C" & MAX(IF(LEFT(B1:F1,1)="C",--MID(B1:F1,2,99)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

*(adjust the B1:F1 to match the cells in your row of interest.)*

Answer (score 0):

In A1, enter formula and copied down :

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(B1:XFD1)="C"),B1:XFD1),LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(B1:XFD1)="P"),B1:XFD1)),"N/A")
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for a quick response! It is my first time posting an excel question on a forum, so I appreciate a quick response!
Your suggested formula does the trick in most cases, but there remains one problem- the versions are often positioned in random places in the string and your formula always returns the right-most cell value. If I have a higher number revision in the middle of an array, it still returns the last value. Is there a way to fix that? Perhaps a MAX formula can be integrated in your formula. I tried modifying your formula, but failed.

Comment: What does the meaning of "a higher number revision in the middle of an array" ? Please give few examples to explain and together with your expected result

Comment: I can't figure out how to post images in comments here... anyway hopefully this makes sense:
Latest Revision: C03.1   Revision 1: P01 Revision 2:C03.1 Revision 3:C02.1 Revision 4:P03 Revision 5: C03
Revision 2 is the latest in this case, so it can be in the middle of an array.